# Inequality from a matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, matrices

Let $\rho(A)$ be the spectral radius of $A,$ that is the maximal eigenvalue of $A$ in absolute value. I want to show that for any $ \rho(A) < \eta < 1,$ there is $c>0$ such that $\|A^k\| \leq c \eta^k$ for $k = 0,1, \dots.$
Can somebody show me how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to be more specific about what you mean by $\|A^t\|$. Which norm? Spectral norm, Frobenius norm, ...?

Comment: Any matrix norm! could this work with any matrix norm? aren't that norms are equivalent in finite dimensional space?

Comment: What is $\eta^t$ here? And do you mean "... want to show that there is $c>0$ so that for any $\eta>\rho(A)$ ... " ? That is, your quantifiers appear to be in the wrong order, and I don't see why $\eta<1$ might be important.

Comment: $\eta=100000000$ trivially satisfies the problem with $c=1$ otherwise.

Comment: @user108903 it does not matter, we could show that $ \|A^t\| < \rho(A)^t$ instead! Because this would implies that $\|A^t\| < \rho(A)^t.$ Since there is $c>0$ such that $ \rho(A)^t \leq c \eta^t$ for $t = 1,2, \dots$ then the inequality would follow. So the question would be, is it true that $\|A^t\| < \rho(A)^t$   for a matrix norm. I want the proof to work for any arbitrary matrix norm

Comment: I got a result that says that if $ \rho(A) < 1,$ there is a matrix norm $ \| \cdot\|$ such that $ \|A\| < 1.$ I don't know how would this help me?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean when you write a superscript $t$ above the real numbers $\eta$ and $\rho(A)$. Is $\eta^t=\eta$?

Comment: $ \eta$ is a real number and $t$ is non-negative integer.

Comment: Not fit for an answer since I am not sure:
If $A$ is diagonalizable, then diagonalize it to $P^{-1}DP$. $$$$
\begin{align}
A^t&\equiv P^{-1}D^tP\\
||A^t||&=||P^{-1}||\cdot||D^t||\cdot||P||\\
\text{If   } ||A^t||&>c\eta^t\quad \forall c,t\\
\implies ||P^{-1}||\cdot||D^t||\cdot||P||&>c\eta^t\quad \forall c,t\\
\implies ||D^t||&>c'\eta^t\quad \forall c',t\\
\end{align}
But I predict there is a contradiction here.

Comment: Oh. Silly me, it looked like a transpose :-)

Comment: @Inquest You're right! the contradiction could come from $c'$ which is arbitrary .  Because, since $ \rho(A) < 1$ then, $\|D^t\| \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow \infty,$ hence $c' \eta^t$ must tend $0$ as $ t \rightarrow \infty$ but if we choose $c' = \frac{1}{ \eta^t}$ then $ c^ \eta^t$ tends to $1$ instead which is a contradiction. We could may be think of more regiorous way to say this or a shorter statement

Comment: You cannot let $c'=\dfrac{1}{\eta^t}$ since $c'$ is a constant.

Comment: @Inquest I agree, thinking of a better thing to say..

Comment: It looks like this is closely related to Gelfand's formula http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius

Comment: @user108903 yes, its in some sense! Gelfand's formula said for any $ \epsilon> 0,$ there is an integer $T$ such that for all $t>T,$ we have $\|A^t\| < (\rho(A) + \epsilon)^t.$

Comment: @Inquest Just one thing!! The same thing could still be done for general matrix $A$ ( weather its digonlizable or not) from Jordan forms.

Comment: @Inquest L'Hôpital's rule would do the trick. By the way, how could you've $\|A^t\| = \|P\|\|D\|\|P^{-1}\|.$ Isn't  $\|A^t\| \leq \|P\|\|D\|\|P^{-1}\|.$ If its the case I don't think the next will follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B=\eta^{-1}A$. Then $\rho(B)<1$. Hence $B^k\rightarrow0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore the entries of $B^k$ are bounded. Hence the Frobenius norm of $B^k$ is bounded and in turn, $\|B^k\|$ is also bounded because all matrix norms are equivalent. Therefore $\|B^k\|\le c$ for some $c>0$, i.e. $\|A^k\|\le c\eta^k$.

Comment: That's what I am talking about.. Nice proof.